# Spell check with Vim and XML automatically

Tags: xml, vim, aspell

When vim checks the spelling of XML documents, it seems to default to checking attributes etc, but not the text between tags. This can easily be fixed by running these two commands:

```
:syn spell toplevel
:redraw
```

I'd like Vim to to do this by default. However, adding these two commands to my vimrc seems to have no affect; they must be performed manually every time I start Vim. Is there another way to make Vim check the spelling between XML tags by default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add an `xml.vim` file in your `~/.vim/after/syntax` directory and put `syn spell toplevel` in it. It should be enough. See `:h mysyntaxfile-add` for further information.